# Angular 7 Reactive Forms Conditional "Required" Validation

Tags: angular, typescript, validation, conditional-statements, angular-reactive-forms

Before I start, I cannot post the code I have written as it's company code with sensitive information but I will provide dummy code..

I'm using Angular 7, Reactive Forms, I have a radio button that is always present on the screen. If you select option "yes", another radio button element shows under it. If you select "no", it doesn't show up or destroys if it's currently visible. (using ngIf*)

What I'm looking to do is something like this:

```
    field: ['', { validators: () => { if (this.isElementShown('blah')) { return Validators.required }}}]
```

Here's the "isElementShown" method:

```
  isElementShown(id: string) {
    var element = document.getElementById(id);
       if (document.body.contains(element)) {
          return true;
       }
    return false;
  }
```

I'm also dumping all of the "invalid" fields on page submit by doing this:

```
  const invalid = [];
  const controls = this.form.controls;
  for (const name in controls) {
    if (controls[name].invalid) {
      invalid.push(name);
    }
  }
  console.log(invalid);
```

The field is not showing as invalid on page load initially, when I click "yes" and the second radio button appears on the screen it shows as invalid. Which is good, that's what I expect it to do. But, when I change the option to "no" on the first radio button it still shows in the console as "invalid". Even though the second radio button is destroyed from the DOM.

Does anybody have any ideas on how to fix this? I feel like I'm ALMOST there. I'm just brain farting at this point! Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Conditional Required you can achieve through required validator of @rxweb/reactive-form-validator.

You just have to set your condition in the required validator.

```js
 second:['',RxwebValidators.required({conditionalExpression:(x)=> {
return x.first == 'yes'
  }})]
```

Complete Code of TS

```js
this.userFormGroup = this.formBuilder.group({
  first:[''],
  second:['',RxwebValidators.required({conditionalExpression:(x)=> {
return x.first == 'yes'
  }})]
})
```

I have registered the 'RxReactiveFormsModule' in the root module.

Check the [**stackblitz example**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-fjingo?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)